# Why is my joblib file not being saved in the same directory as my Jupyter file?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to create a persistent model for a machine learning project. I'm using `joblib.dump` to do so. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from joblib import dump

music_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\obaro\OneDrive\Documents\music.csv")
X = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = music_data['genre']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

dump(model, "music-recommender.joblib")
```

In the Jupiter notebook, the output seems to provide what I'm looking for,
`['music-recommender.joblib']` just a string of the file name. I can't find this file anywhere though. What's going on? I'm running windows 10 if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either save your file with an absolute path, or set the relative path relative to your current working directory:

```
music_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\obaro\OneDrive\Documents\music.csv")
X = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = music_data['genre']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

dump(model, r"C:\Users\obaro\OneDrive\Documents\music-recommender.joblib")
```

To find out your current working directory, use

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

and then set relative from there.

Comment: Thank you! That worked!  Okay, now I don't know if this is the proper place to ask, but when I try to load() the dump I get an error.: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list. Any idea what this could be from?

Comment: Great :) don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.